# More than one dataset

Tags: apache-superset

Does anyone know if there is any development forecast so that it will be possible to use more than one dataset to create a graph? A more intuitive way to merge more than one table, as Oracle's Analytics and Microsoft's PowerBi does, is by identifying the common information (foreign keys) of the tables involved and making a join. I know you can do this through SQL Lab, but for users without knowledge of SQL it is complicated.

Superset is missing a more intuitive interface for concatenating tables, instead of doing it with SQL. Users who do not have knowledge of SQL were unable to do this.